# Can't access attributes on a list of objects while trying to get vpce id from cloudngfwaws_ngfw resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to get the endpoint_id and store it in an ssm parameter from a cloudngfwaws_ngfw but getting an error:

> Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
> the attribute "attachment" for a specific element of the list, or
> across all elements of the list?

My code:

```
resource "cloudngfwaws_ngfw" "the_cloud_ngfw" {
  count  = length(local.subnet_id_list)
  name        = "${var.projectname}-cloudngfw-${local.account_id}-${local.az_list[count.index]}-${count.index}"
  vpc_id      = local.vpc_id
  account_id  = local.account_id
  description = "NGFW resource for Project ${var.projectname}"
  endpoint_mode = "ServiceManaged"
  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = local.subnet_id_list[count.index]
  }
  rulestack = "${var.env_name}-${var.rule_stack_name}"
  tags = {
    project = var.projectname
  }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "the_cloud_ngfw_endpoint" {
  count  = length(local.subnet_id_list)
  name  = "myngfw/endpoint${count.index}"
  type  = "String"
  value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[*].status.attachment.endpoint_id
}
```

Comment: You probably want `value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[count.index].status.attachment.endpoint_id`.

Comment: @MarkoE already tried this with same error

Comment: Ah, ok the `attachment` is actually a list. So something like `value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[count.index].status.attachment[*].endpoint_id`?

Comment: @MarkoE same error as will when trying your last comment.

Comment: It would actually be helpful to see what does e.g. `cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[0].status.attachment[0].endpoint_id` output, of course omitting any sensitive values.

Comment: @MarkoE same error │ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 40, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "the_cloud_ngfw_endpoint":
│   40:   value = cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw[0].status.attachment[0].endpoint_id
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access
│ attribute "attachment" for a specific element of the list, or across all
│ elements of the list?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `cloudngfwaws_ngfw.the_cloud_ngfw` I get a feeling that object is not the way you expect

Comment: According to the documentation `status` is also a list: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/PaloAltoNetworks/cloudngfwaws/latest/docs/resources/ngfw#status